# How to use rapidshare api?

Tags: php, rapidshare

I am trying to use rapidshare apis but dont know exactly how to use it?

http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?subroutine=getaccountdetails_v1&type=prem&login=MY_USERNAME&password=MY_PASSWORD

after using this i am getting error "ERROR: Subroutine invalid."

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my link?

Comment: Do you have a premium account?

Comment: yes.... i have rs account and its working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is although the API defines the subroutine as 
`subroutine=getaccountdetails_v1` what it actually requires is
`sub=getaccountdetails_v1`. This applies for all the subroutine calls.

This should work

`http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=getaccountdetails_v1&type=prem&login=MY_USERNAME&password=MY_PASSWORD`

[click here](http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=getaccountdetails_v1&type=prem&login=MY_USERNAME&password=MY_PASSWORD)

Answer (score 0):

But I think it should be something like this

https://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=getaccountdetails&type=prem&login=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASS